# merge multiindex dataframe with unequal length

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multi-index

here are my two dataframes

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],[1,2]],names=['one','two'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[10,20,30,40]}, index = index)
df
          col
 one two     
 a   1     10
     2     20
 b   1     30
     2     40

index_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],[1.,2],['abc','mno','xyz']], names = ['one','two','three'])
temp =  pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}, index = index_1)
temp
                col1
 one two three      
  a   1.0 abc       1
          mno       2
          xyz       3
      2.0 abc       4
          mno       5
          xyz       6
  b   1.0 abc       7
          mno       8
          xyz       9
      2.0 abc      10
          mno      11
          xyz      12
```

how can I merge both of them?
I have tried, this

```
pd.merge(left = temp, right = df, left_on = temp.index.levels[0], right_on = df.index.levels[0])
```

but this does not work

```
KeyError: "Index([u'a', u'b'], dtype='object', name=u'one') not in index"
```

if I convert the index into columns through reset_index() than the merge works. However, I wish to achieve this while preserving the index structure.

my desired output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***method 1***
`reset_index` + `merge`

```
df.reset_index().merge(temp.reset_index()).set_index(index_1.names)
```

***method 2***
`join` with `reset_index` partial

```
df.join(temp.reset_index('three')).set_index('three', append=True)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this works. I was fiddling around with pd.merge and pd.reset_index for a long time, but didn't strike me that I could use them this way. Can you suggest, how can i improve my skills working on time series data in pandas?

Comment: @SirajS. best way is to try and answer these questions on stackoverflow... no joke!